# Nessus scan continues to find EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA enabled despite being disabled in SSLCipherSuite

Tags: openssl

I am a complete novice when it comes to server security but I'll try to properly explain my issue.

I am trying to disable cipher suites for Apache TLS termination on my Mac Server to pass a nessus scan, and I have been able to pass all but one `EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA` which keeps seeming to fail. I have looked around and can't seem to find an answer to this. The conf file for my server is below. This is what I got from looking different blogs but it don't seem to work.

`Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/0000_any_443_www.mySite.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:34580>
ServerName http://mysitte.com:80
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/myfoler"
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php default.html
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combinedvhost
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine Off
    SSLCipherSuite "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA"
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
</IfModule>
<Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/myfolder">
    Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        DAV Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
        Require all denied
        ErrorDocument 403 /customerror/websitesoff403.html
    </IfDefine>
</Directory>
```

When I run the test

```
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA...YES !!!!!!!!!!!!(This is failling)
Testing EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing DES-CBC3-SHA...YES
Testing PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA...NO (no ciphers available)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing AECDH-NULL-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
Testing NULL-SHA256...NO (sslv3 alert handshake failure)
```

Comment: Just a random guess, but… did you restart apache after changing the config file?

Comment: @Ángel Yes. Several times.